# After reinstalling MAMP PRO, apps can't find databases

Tags: php, mysql, database, mamp, mamp-pro

Thanks to MAMP PRO's *amazing* uninstaller, which deletes all of your databases, I had to restore them from the online versions.  The only problem is now, when I take code that is working online and databases that are working online, the code can't find the databases.  With MAMP PRO running, I can see the databases via command-line as such:

```
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| donatetheweight    |
| mysql              |
| natiood8_wrd1      |
| performance_schema |
| personalprpro      |
| test               |
+--------------------+
```

And I have permissions:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                                                                                              |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*2E80906F903DA9B84678ED79A48FF414B4FDC890' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION                                                                           |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Not to mention I can use Sequel Pro to see the databases on localhost.  In my code, I am using the Fat-Free Framework, which works fine online and did before I reinstalled.  Here is the command:

```
$f3->db = new \DB\SQL(
      'mysql:host=localhost;port=8889;dbname=donatetheweight',
      'root',
      'notroot'
    );
```

My MAMP PRO is set to MAMP ports (http->8888, https->8890, mysql->8889) and I am accessing my site through the correct host on port 8888.  The error I get is an internal server error [1049] etc:

[image]

Anything else I can try?  I did notice for a while I was getting a my.cnf file conflict but I accidentally clicked "Do not show this again" so I can't be sure where to look for that error.

Just to be sure that the database existed (and that this isn't a duplicate of [ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118627/error-1049-42000-unknown-database), I tried to recreate the database and got this:

```
mysql> create database donatetheweight;
ERROR 1007 (HY000): Can't create database 'donatetheweight'; database exists
```

Comment: I don't think you need the port number. try it without the port number

Comment: How would it know to use port 8889 then, given that the default port number is 3306?  P.S. Tried it and still getting the same error.

Comment: It should be defaulted to the correct port.

Comment: Well unfortunately, it didn't.  I just removed the text `port=8889;` and it gave the same error, only without the port in the error text.

Comment: Can you connect to another database?

Comment: Good question; no I cannot.  I tried both of those other listed non-default DBs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118627/error-1049-42000-unknown-database check that link it might help

Answer (score 0):

Verify your mysql.sock file is missing (use `mysqladmin variables` to see where it is looking and check there), restart your computer, start up MAMP (not PRO), then MAMP PRO.  Double check by ensuring your changes persist using two database tools (I used Sequel Pro and PHPMyAdmin).